# Bash Shell While inside for loop not working- Picking only first value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, while-loop

I am running a simple while loop inside a for loop, below is my code. My problem is when running this code the while loop is picking only first line from the file iplist.txt.

Need to understand why my while loop is not running for the whole file line by line.

```
for node in `nodeset -e @nishant1`;

do
while read -r q; do

nslookup $q | grep uhc |awk '{print $4}' >/tmp/nslookup.txt

dest=`cat /tmp/nslookup.txt`

clush -w $node "sh /opt/OV/qa-ira/ira/bin/ira setProbe ICMP -on BDPassS -op icmpEcho -ta $q -tn ICMP_'$node'_'$dest' -tt IPv4 -ds 256"


done< /iplist.txt

done
```

Comment: Include a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `clush` command also reads from `stdin` so it consumed all other lines in the file. So try like this:

```
#
# prevent clush from reading current stdin
#
clush -w $node ... < /dev/null
```

Comment: just installed clush and tried. it turns out clush uses ssh (by default at least). ssh reading from stdin is a well known feature/bug. :)